# Dynamic link for same html file with JS

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to link to the same html and getting a different link dependning on if you've clicked this or that href? Say I have 1.000 different books. If I click the link for book #1 it takes me to that book's page, if I click on book #4 it takes me to book #4's page and so on. Now, since the structure is the same for every book; ISBN, author, pages, price and so on, is there a way for me to use the same html file instead of copy and paste and rename the same html 999 times AND still have a unique link to send to friends? Something like the anchor points maybe?

Working in JS.

Comment: How are you creating the links? With Javacript? If yes post the code of your html and js

Comment: You can make an array of objects containing all of data for your books and in JS map through that array creating inside map function anchor tags inserting as src link to that books, and so on... But, for creating what you want, dynamically loaded html content, it would be better to make SPA in Angular, Vue or React

Comment: @MichaelMontero Right now I don't have a solution to that. With a html for every book you'd just link to that book's dedicated html with href.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted your code, I don't know how you've made the buttons but something like this might do the job (btw the arrays might be loaded from some database, txt file or anything else, this is just demonstration):

```js
var names = ["Books 1's name", "Books 2's name", "Books 3's name"];
var authors = ["Books 1's author", "Books 2's author", "Books 3's author"];

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 

  document.write("<button onclick=\"rewrite(" + i + ")\">" + names[i] + "</button>");

}

function rewrite(index){
  
  document.getElementById("nameLabel").innerHTML = names[index];
  document.getElementById("authorLabel").innerHTML = authors[index];

}
```

```html
<p id="nameLabel">Name of the book</p>
<p id="authorLabel">Author's name</p>
```